# cv2 frame write file taking too much size

Tags: python, opencv

Screenshot:

[image]

Essentially I'm trying to make a folder with all the frames a video has, and editing it later in the code, however, I'm facing a problem of the file size of the img/frame being too high when saved which I have been trying to look into but I had no luck so far.

**Any help will be appreciated!**

```
VideoCap = cv2.VideoCapture("./Path/Path.mp4");

FolderPath = "./Path/Path";

if not os.path.exists(FolderPath):
    print(f"{FolderPath} doesn't exists. Creating...");
    os.makedirs(FolderPath);

    Success, Frame = VideoCap.read();
    Count = 0;

    while Success:
        cv2.imwrite(FolderPath+"/Frame%d.png" % Count, Frame); # The size is way too much! Literally 1/15th of the video just in a frame.
        print("Frame %d has been written" % Count);
        Count+=1;
        Success, Frame = VideoCap.read();
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
else:
    print(f"{FolderPath} already exists. Moving on...");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use compression parameters while writing image. Refer the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-last-rst/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html?highlight=imread)

```
cv2.imwrite(filename, img,  [cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION, compression_value])
#compression_value range 0-9
```

For PNG, it can be the compression level ( CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION ) from 0 to 9. A higher value means a smaller size and longer compression time. Default value is 3.

Comment: Thank you for your help; While I did use it, it didn't reduce the image size by a lot, maybe around 200kb at most. I found an easier way of doing this, I just made the png (file extension) to jpg, and resized it using cv2!

Comment: Png is for lossless compression and jpg for lossy compression. So jpg can be compressed to a greater extent.